# Simulate the running of a "make install" -- a "dry run" or simulator utility?

Tags: software-installation, make

Is there a generic way of running a bash script and seeing the commands that result, but not actually run the commands - i.e. a  "dry run"/simulator of sorts?

I have a database install script (actually "make install" after running ./configure and make) that I wish to run, but it's installing all sorts of stuff that I don't want.

So I'd like a way to see exactly what it's going to do before I run it for real - maybe even run the commands by hand instead.

Is there any utility that can perform such a task (or anything related/similar)?

Comment: I think 'set -n' does something like that. Try adding -x as well.

Comment: How do I pipe "make install" to set -n?

Comment: `bash -n make install`, but from `man bash`: "An interactive shell may ignore this option."

Comment: There is no dryrun option in `bash`. See also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115156/show-commands-without-executing-them

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[GNU make has an option](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Instead-of-Execution.html#Instead-of-Execution) to do a dry-run:

> ‘-n’
>
> ‘--just-print’
>
> ‘--dry-run’
>
> ‘--recon’
>
> “No-op”. Causes make to print the recipes that are needed to make the targets
>   up to date, but not actually execute them. Note that some recipes are
>   still executed, even with this flag (see How the MAKE Variable Works).
>   Also any recipes needed to update included makefiles are still
>   executed.

So for your situation, just run `make -n install` to see the commands that `make` would execute.

Comment: BTW, the `-n`, `--justprint`, `--dry-run` and `--recon` options also all work in CMake. You can check this using `cmake --help` or `man cmake`. The four options seem to be equivalent/synonymous.

Answer (score 9):

Any version of **`make`** has a `-n` option (see [POSIX description of `make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html)), but the ***shell*** has no corresponding option (see for example *[Show commands without executing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115156/show-commands-without-executing-them)*).

To aggravate the situation, if you happen to use automake, it pastes-in large chunks of boilerplate scripting (which its developers refer to as "recursive rules") which defeat the ability of anyone to use "make -n" and see what will happen.

Further reading:

- *[27.11 Debugging Make Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Debugging-Make-Rules.html)*

  > `make -n` can help show what would be done without actually doing it. Note however, that this will still execute commands prefixed with `‘+’`, and, when using GNU make, commands that contain the strings `‘$(MAKE)’` or `‘${MAKE}’` (see [Instead of Execution](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Instead-of-Execution.html#Instead-of-Execution) in The GNU Make Manual). Typically, this is helpful to show what recursive rules would do, but it means that, in your own rules, you *should not mix such recursion* with actions that change any files. Furthermore, note that GNU make will update prerequisites for the Makefile file itself even with -n (see [Remaking Makefiles](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html#Remaking-Makefiles) in The GNU Make Manual).
- [Re: More problems with `make -n' in automake-generated rules.](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake-patches/2010-11/msg00004.html)
  touches on some of the pitfalls listed in *[27.9 Handling Tools that Produce Many Outputs](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Multiple-Outputs.html)*